# jQuery Delegate fails to run ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Here is my jQuery using delegate and ajax:

```
$(".tweets").delegate("#fav #submit", "click", function(){
    var favid = $("#fav input#favid").val();
    var favsave = 'favid=' + favid;
    alert(favsave);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "fav.php",
      data: favsave,
      success: function() {
        $('#fav').fadeOut(100);
      }
    });
    return false;

});
```

The HTML:

```
   <div class='tweets'>
    <ul class='entries'>
      <li>
        <form id='fav' method='post' class='favo' action=''>
          <input style='display: none;' type='text' name='fav' id='fav' value='".$row["tweetid"]."' />
          <input type='submit' value='Add to Favorites' name='submit' id='submit' />
        </form>"
      </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
```

There is another set of Ajax on the page that is constantly adding to the .entries list, these records that get appended pickup the click function, so that when I click on them the Alerts are shown but the Ajax part of the function doesnt work.

Any ideas? Would .live be better?

Comment: Ok looks like its only ever getting the first record in the list as the ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"doesn't work" is not the best of all descriptions.

Anyway, it makes no sense to use "absolute" selectors within an delegated event.
By querying `$("#fav input#favid").val();` <strike>you would get results from all elements with that id</strike>
you would only get the first match (since `ids` are assumed to be unique) (which would be unfortunate just because of multiple `id tags`)

You should grab the `target` property from the `event object` to identify the elements which should get involved.

Example:

```
$(".tweets").delegate("#submit", "click", function(event){
    var $self   = $(event.target);
    var favid   = $self.siblings('#fav');
    var favsave = 'favid=' + favid;

    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "fav.php",
          data: favsave,
          success: function() {
                $self.closests('#fav').fadeOut(100);
          }
    });
    return false;
});
```

It's probably not a good idea to have `IDs` for elements which are created dynamically.
As mentioned, it's no valid `HTML markup` to have multiple `ID` tags. Should be classes I guess.